Complex types definition: instance field vs. instance method
I have been struggling to build two kind of type definitions helpers, a bit like Omit<...>, InstanceType<...>, etc.
I'll give one here:
class C {
    method() {}
    field: ()=> void = ()=> {}
}

I'm looking to make a definition ClassMethod<C> for example who would retrieve, in this case, only 'method'
I'm not even sure it is possible
PS: Of course, any variant like this would be doing the job:
Fields<C> giving
{
    field: ()=> void
}

Though, I'd still love to end up with a generic Methods<C>

your question is quite cumbersome, what sense in using AbstractMethod that returns a non abstract method field?

TypeScript does not encode at the type level the difference between inherited vs own properties. There's a longstanding feature request for this (more or less) at ms/TS#9726. So there's no way to write a utility type that selects just the methods (inherited function-valued properties). TypeScript has some representation of this, but it only happens at the value level, so you need a class instance value as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

TypeScript's type system does not represent whether an object property is inherited/own or enumerable/non-enumerable. Since methods are essentially just inherited function-valued properties, that means you can't write a Methods<T> utility type that would reliably distinguish methods from function-valued fields. More generally, any JavaScript functionality that depends on property inheritance and enumerability cannot be accurately modeled in TypeScript. There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#9726 for encoding the enumerability and inheritance of objects in  the type system, and if that were ever to be implemented, you could probably make meaningful progress here. Until and unless that happens you'll need to give up or work around it.
The closest thing to a workaround I can think of is to deal with a concrete class instance value. The type level of TypeScript can't help you, but it does keep a little information at the value level.  In particular, if you have a class instance value and spread it into a new object, TypeScript does know enough to suppress the methods from appearing as properties in the new object. See microsoft/TypeScript#13409 and issues linked within for more information.  So you could write:
class C {
  method() { }
  field: () => void = () => { }
}

declare const c: C;
const d = { ...c };
type Methods = Exclude<keyof C, keyof typeof d>;
//   ^? type Methods = "method"

But this does not extend to the type level. You need that value c to exist (or for TypeScript to think it exists) to get that information. And it's therefore fragile; if you try to transform the type C with a mapped type or other type function before declaring a value of the type, it's quite likely the information you care about will be lost.
So you can't use this to build an accurate Methods<T> that works for generic T, and you can't use it to build one that works purely on the type level. Still, some use cases might be satisfied by this workaround or one like it with similar caveats. Otherwise you'll just have to give up (e.g., don't put function-valued properties in a class instance type directly, or give them known names, etc).
Playground link to code

Can you distinguish a method from a field with an arrow function based on their this parameter?

I don’t think TS tracks the difference between arrow functions and function expressions or methods, except at the value level. And there’s no —strictThis so the this parameter of a method will be void unless manually added.

Hm then how does the unbound-method eslint rule do it? I had assumed they only rely on the type.

Good question. ESLint rules use the compiler API and have access to the TypeScript syntax tree for the code. So they see more than just types, but a representation of the actual code. So they can inspect ts.SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration for example, but that's not part of the type.

At a moment, after seeing your playground code, I thought at creating an auxiliary generic function who returns { ...c } to use ReturnType. But it didn't do the job...
